# Django separate model class to two

Tags: django, django-models

I have one model class like this:

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Games_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Win_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Los_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Eve_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Game_mean = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Best_game = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Event = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Team_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I have collected all the data to database, but now I think it is better to separate Team name to another class (because same team can be in different events). So my question is: is it possible to separate classes afterwards? That in the end I would have something like this:

```
class Team_event(models.Model):
    Team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Games_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Win_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Los_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Eve_n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Game_mean = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Best_game = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Event = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Team_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Teams(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: This is what database migrations are for

Comment: the problem is that I have all the team names, so how can I "move" that info to different class ?

Comment: You'll need a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), create the teams model first, make a data migration, then make a second migration to introduce the foreign key

Comment: Is there any examples somewhere how to do that? I don't want to lose any data, by trying the wrong, so clear example/guide would be lovely.

Comment: Theres one in the link above

Comment: So first I run migration that renames the old class and makes the new class, then move all the data to the new class, but how to I update ForeigneKeys?